# Выделение памяти для массива с использованием больших чисел

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь разобраться, как выделять память для массивов с использованием больших чисел. Я понимаю, что нельзя выделить память, если у типа данных нет size_t. Вот, например, использую библиотеку boost(если есть другие, которые лучше подойдут, посоветуйте пожалуйста)

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int128_t v = 68718952447;
int128_t *r;

    r = new int128_t[sqrt(v)];
```

В последней строчке ошибка, я понимаю, это из-за того, что int128_t нет size_t. Вот как выкрутиться можно? Думаю тут наверное, когда выделяешь память под значения, надо конвектировать в тип, где есть size_t, но как это сделать не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать правильно.

Comment: А что должно вернуть взятие квадратного корня у типа?

Comment: @Unick тип меньшего размера, очевидно :)

Comment: ошибся)исправил

Comment: Вот я не знаю как перевести из этого типа в меньший, если размер числа позволяет. Наверное надо int128_t конвектриовать в __int64 наверное, но как сделать не знаю

Comment: Пробовать каст, если не поможет - как крайний случай - юнион всё кастит.

Comment: `v.convert_to<size_t>()` не работает? А где вы возьмете столько памяти?

Comment: Может быть приведёте текст ошибки?

Comment: @VTT что-то Вы упорно сопротивляетесь написанию ответов в ответах :)

Comment: "...что int128_t нет size_t" - что означает эта фраза вообще?

Comment: Неявно приводится

Comment: как написал, VTT сработало, но я не понимаю как выделяется память. `r = new mp::int128_t[sqrt(v.convert_to<size_t>())];`. В квадратных скобках написано сколько элементов умноженное на размер int128_t. Правильно понял?

Comment: @Александр `sqrt(v).convert_to...`.

Comment: спасибо, исправил)